# SASS create multiple variables at once

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, less

Is it possible to create a single SASS variable using map that then creates a variable for each key-value pair?

For example, I want this:

```
$heading: (   
    1: 5rem,   
    2: 4.5rem,   
    3: 4rem,  
    4: 3.5rem,   
    5: 3rem,   
    6: 2.5rem );
```

to turn into this:

```
$heading-1: 5rem; 
$heading-2: 4.5rem; 
$heading-3: 4rem; 
$heading-4: 3.5rem; 
$heading-5: 3rem; 
$heading-6: 2.5rem;
```

I used the map to create class names for each variation, but I want to create the variables themselves and not the class names.

Answer (score 1):

Maps are used to give you a more hierarchical way of visualising and referencing groups of data/values. You can use values from maps using `map-get`:

```css
/* Map */
$heading: (   
    1: 5rem,   
    2: 4.5rem,   
    3: 4rem,  
    4: 3.5rem,   
    5: 3rem,   
    6: 2.5rem 
);

/* Use map-get to make use of values from a map */
.heading-5 {
    font-size: map-get($heading, 5);
}

/* Output */
.heading-5 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

You could have a simple function to use these, too:

```css
/* Map */
$heading: (   
    1: 5rem,   
    2: 4.5rem,   
    3: 4rem,  
    4: 3.5rem,   
    5: 3rem,   
    6: 2.5rem 
);

/* Simple reusable function to reference heading sizes */
@function heading($heading-size) {
    @return map-get($heading, $heading-size);
}

.heading-4 {
    font-size: heading(4);
}

/* Output */
.heading-4 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want individual variables then you should just make individual variables.

Related: You can use an `@each` loop to produce CSS custom properties (rather than sass variables), which may actually suit your use case:

```css
/* Map */
$heading: (   
    1: 5rem,   
    2: 4.5rem,   
    3: 4rem,  
    4: 3.5rem,   
    5: 3rem,   
    6: 2.5rem 
);

/* Use an @each loop to generate CSS custom properties for all the map entries */
:root {
    @each $heading-level, $heading-size in $heading {
       --heading-#{$heading-level}: #{$heading-size};
    }
}

/* Output */
:root {
  --heading-1: 5rem;
  --heading-2: 4.5rem;
  --heading-3: 4rem;
  --heading-4: 3.5rem;
  --heading-5: 3rem;
  --heading-6: 2.5rem;
}
```